# How to debug a fixed position header when the window gets smaller?

Tags: css, header, css-position, window-resize

OK I have a fixed position header on my page. It is working correctly and everything... But I have a big problem with it -> When I try to make the browser window smaller, the content (in this case, the menu) gets out of the header's `div`.

How could I fix this? Is there any way to do it?

**EDIT:**
I want the header to stay in fixed position.

[if you want to check the problem out in action, go to: http://www.chilledlime.com and then make your browser window smaller]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why dont you just let the header be in the flow of the page and have it center align? what is the idea behind using `position:fixed` ?

Comment: I would like to have it as `position: fixed;` because of better navigation and for other reasons...

Comment: and you dont matter if the links falls?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:fixed` from `#logobox`:

```css
#logobox {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
    border: 0 none;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: fixed; <----- this -----
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
#logobox ul {
display: inline;
list-style: none;
padding-top: 15px;
width: 65%;
}
```

and you can add or not an "overflow:hidden" to "#logobox", it depends of what you are looking for